# Auto draft posts when scheduled date is reached

Tags: post-status, wp-update-post, scheduled-posts, draft, automation

I have a plugin that allows all scheduled posts to be visible immediately...

I'm looking for a function that will automatically set a post's status to "draft" when it reaches it's scheduled date and time. This function needs to be dynamic to allow for posts to be edited (in case they further extend or shorten their scheduled date).

Much appreciated

Comment: Could you elaborate on why a bit? How is this different from simply a draft with a future date?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Why do you need to schedule published posts if you don't actually want them published? How is it different from simply keeping them as drafts?

Comment: I'm making a job board of sorts and the scheduled date is the expiry date. All scheduled posts are published immediately.

Comment: Post cannot be simultaneously scheduled and published in native mechanics. As above — please elaborate a bit what you are trying to accomplish and what you already have working. :)

Comment: Question updated